# Which combinations are popular during which years?

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

I know that there are topic/genre combos that work better than others, and I know that different target audiences like certain types of games and platforms more than others. All of that is easy enough to find on the game's wiki and elsewhere.

What I can't seem to find any information on is which types of games are popular at different times of different years. I know that it can affect a game's score, but the only one I've been able to find out for sure is that a Medieval/RPG works well toward the end of Y20. I'm not sure if it's true for an extended range of time around that or just that specific moment.

Does anyone else know more about this combo timing?

Comment: Answers to this will also change slightly depending on if you pick a long or short game. As the times are compressed

Comment: Long or short in terms of development time? The time it keeps selling for? Larger games do take longer to finish developing, but certain games "click" better if you manage to release them within a certain range of time. I did one playthrough where a Fantasy/RPG on the Gameling got me a near perfect score and $5 million, and another playthrough where the same game released at a different time got mediocre scores and sales.

Comment: I meant the long or short game as in how many years you pick game dev tycoon to go for,

Comment: The 30-year version.

Comment: Answers to this can be highly subjective and it depends on which market/demography/country you're trying to look at. But if you were to ask me, (without any statistical proof), I'd say that its Arcade and Platforming during 1990's, RTS/FPS from 2000 onwards

Answer (score 2):

According to the game's [raw data](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/Raw_Data_for_Review_Algorithm/1.4.3), the algorithm that calculates how big of a score a game will get, does not include the year. What does matter however, is the console that you release your game on. So focus on the console rather than the year. You may get messages every once in a while that tells you what console is the best one to choose.